# Locking Failed! pipenv install requests

Tags: python, django, pipenv

So i am trying to learn python and we were told that we will be using Django. As an advance, I tried setting up the environment, I ran into this problem right after typing in

```
pipenv install requests
```

The result is as follows

```
Installing requests…
Adding requests to Pipfile's [packages]…
Installation Succeeded
Pipfile.lock not found, creating…
Locking [dev-packages] dependencies…
Locking [packages] dependencies…
Locking Failed!
Unable to create process using 
'c:\.......\python\python39\python.exe"c:/....../python/python39/lib/site- 
packages/pipenv/resolver.py"'
```

Can anyone help me with this problem please.